# Why do you need to change the Hostname of your EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

There is a topic in EC2 documentation [Changing the System Hostname](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html). Why does one need to change it? Just for fun? Just to have some nice shell prompt?

```
// change this
ubuntu@ip-123-12-1-231 ~ $

// to this?
ubuntu@my-beautiful-hostname ~ $
```

I'm learning how AWS DNS work, where my EC2's DNS lives that resolves a default Public DNS name to Public IP address of my instance

Public DNS: `ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Public IP: `xx-xx-xxx-xx`

And how can I host multiple apps with real domain names (`example1.com`, `example2.com`, so on) in one EC2 instance, how to modify and manage DNS. And actually I don't know what to read about it in docs, and read everything related to hostnames and DNS, and found this topic `Changing the System Hostname` and don't understand why would one want to change a hostname and if it can be valuable info for me.

**UPD**:

And now a real a practical question for those specimens who like closing questions quietly.

Where does a DNS live in EC2 instance? How is `Public DNS` mapped to `Public IP`? Where is that record in my EC2 Ubuntu instance? Is Route53 involved in it?

Comment: Changing the hostname is unnecessary unless the instance, itself, or the code running there, for some reason, needs to know the hostname.  Nothing to do with external resolution.

Answer (score 0):

> Where does a DNS live in EC2 instance?

It doesn't, DNS resolution use by the server is set in /etc/resolv.conf and /etc/nsswitch.conf.  The hostname domain name for that server is set (Redhat derived systems) in /etc/sysconfig/network

> How is Public DNS mapped to Public IP?

With a DNS record

> Where is that record in my EC2 Ubuntu instance?

In the DNS for the domain that you have attached it to

> Is Route53 involved in it?

Only if you are using Route53 for DNS

Answer (score 0):

EC2 DNS location ([source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html?shortFooter=true#amazon-dns-server)):

> In **EC2-Classic**, the Amazon DNS server is located at 172.16.0.23.
>
> In **EC2-VPC**, the Amazon DNS server is located at the base of your VPC network range plus two.

For more information, see [Amazon DNS Server](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html?shortFooter=true#AmazonDNS) in the Amazon VPC User Guide

Answer (score 0):

Well i had the same issue as you did and someone replied me this

> It isn't a huge deal if you are just running a single server, mostly
>   to help you identify a server with local networking. Some things like
>   mail servers will use your hostname unless you specify otherwise.

[This is an example of somewhere I saw that done](https://youtu.be/Sa_kQheCnds?t=739)

My original query

> why do some people set hostname and some dont? whats the use?
>   hostnamectl set-hostname